# properties of a class to be compared with columns in excel sheet

Tags: c#-4.0

How to compare properties of a class with columns in excel sheet ?

Answer (score 0):

i dont know how to get the columns of an excel sheet, but i am sure, thats very simple (i never did this till now).

To retrieve the properties of a class, you can use the GetProperties method of the type:

```
foreach (var propertyInfo in this.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public))
{
    Console.WriteLine(propertyInfo.Name);
}
```

cherio,
Chris